# How to use index.php?p= instead of page.php

Tags: php

I have seen some websites using index.php?p=page instead of page.php. I would like to know what the best way to do that using php is, and if there's any advantages to that.

Comment: routing to all pages via index.php and proper use of htaccess

Comment: Kids these days call it "front controller" pattern. Consolidating initalization (backend, authorization, templating, etc.) is why it's usually preferred.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to some other answers. I noticed in the second one, there was some quick and dirty ways to do it, but I would like something thats simple but not really quick and dirty.